# Shader won't work for me in opengl

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am following a tutorial by dermetfan on shaders and although my code seems to be pretty much identical, it does not perform what is intended. No compiling error happens and no logs are written.

```
    ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/red.vsh"), Gdx.files.internal("shaders/red.fsh"));
    System.out.println(shader.isCompiled() ? "Compiled shader!" : shader.getLog());
    batch.setShader(shader);
```

and this code is the vsh

```
    attribute vec4 a_color;
    attribute vec3 a_position;
    attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

    uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

    varying vec4 v_color;
    varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

    void main(void) {
        v_color = a_color;
        v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
        gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.);
    }
```

and heres the .fsh

```
 varying vec4 v_color;
 varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

 uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;

 void main() {

     gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler2D, v_texCoord0) * v_color;
     gl_FragColor = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.);

 }
```

If i get rid of the shader my texture loads just fine, however when I run with the shader my textures seem to vanish.

EDIT
Please try to stray from looking for errors in the code, ShaderProgram.pedantic = false and I know for a fact my code is identical to the tutorial I am watching and yet his works and mine doesn't. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are there any messages in the shader log? Have you also tried using `in` and `out` instead of varying and attribute?

Comment: "no logs are written" and yes no change, thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: Is your shader supposed to do something with a texture? Right now it doesn't access any textures, so no textures are accessed.

Comment: yes the batch is controling my players texture

Comment: I am assuming the file extension `.fsh` means fragment shader. Assuming you did not mis-paste the second shader, this program will never link because it's the same vertex shader twice.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman no, it shouldn't be a problem with pedantic off, it's a simple passthrough shader and now for some reason it is only drawing certain images even though all images are being drawn with same batch.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I am confident in the codes ability to run because it is straight from a tutorial that I spent 30 minutes analyzing and making sure all is exactly the same before asking the question and with such little code 30 minutes was more then enough time to realize it can't be a code error

Comment: What tutorial are you following? No GLSL compiler should compile that second shader when it's told it is a fragment shader, because it writes to `gl_Position` and uses `attribute`. Neither of those things are valid.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman "dermetfan" here is the link! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mIdNru2VO0
Thank you for any help and really looking into my question!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I am very sorry please look at revision to .fsh code!!

Comment: You should not assign `gl_FragColor` twice like that. Right now it's just going to be red, but if you comment out the second assignment it will use your texture.

Comment: That is the problem. I want it to be red, but it isn't! @AndonM.Coleman

Comment: Are you using SpriteBatch?If so,compare the default shader of the spritebatch to yours and you will find that SB is referring to the texture sampler as u_texture and not as u_sampler2D but I think this would had throwned an exception so probably that's not case.